# Java - implementation instances inside an interface

Tags: java

In my project I need to create objects for each kind of Java Math Operator like "Add", "Substraction", "Multiplication", etc. And these operators should be singletons.

So here is what I am going to do. I define the Math Operator as an interface and I put those implementations inside it as I don't want to define singleton classes for each operator.

```
public interface MathOperator {


double operate(double a, double b);

MathOperator ADD = new MathOperator(){

    @Override
    public double operate(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }

};

MathOperator SUBSTRACT = new MathOperator(){

    @Override
    public double operate(double a, double b) {
        return a - b;
    }

};  

}
```

I don't see much of such usage when I Google this. So I wonder if this is a good practice and if there are better and more graceful approaches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do smt like

1) Define interface

```
interface MathOperator {
    double operate(double a, double b);
}
```

2) Than have some common implementation in enum (less code)

```
enum MathOperators implements MathOperator {
    ADD {
        @Override
        public double operate(double a, double b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    },

    SUBTRACT {
        @Override
        public double operate(double a, double b) {
            return a - b;
        }
    }
}
```

3) Or public static members (more clean solution).

```
class MathOperators {
    public static MathOperator ADD = new MathOperator() {
        @Override
        public double operate(double a, double b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    };
    public static MathOperator SUBTRACT = new MathOperator() {
        @Override
        public double operate(double a, double b) {
            return a - b;
        }
    };
}
```

- can create new `MathOperator` without changing `MathOperators`
- have nice API for common operations
- shouldn't write singletons
- have nice clean interface

Comment: You need to make `MathOperators` implement `MathOperator` otherwise you are not @Override-ing anything.

Comment: Yep, this looks better I will take the 'enum implements interface' solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

One idiom that I've seen used in precisely these circumstances is the use of `enum`:

```
public enum MathOperator {

    ADD {
        @Override
        public double operate(double a, double b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    },

    SUBTRACT {
        @Override
        public double operate(double a, double b) {
            return a - b;
        }
    };

    public abstract double operate(double a, double b);

}
```

Comment: enums are OK when you have a finite number of possible impls, but when you just want some common ones handy, the interface constants rule. What you *could* do though is have `enum MathOperatorImpl implements MathOperator`! I like that even better!! :D

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian, I will take the 'enum implements interface' solution.

Comment: @Bohemian I remember such a recommendation in Effective Java, to use interfaces for emulating extensible enums. I think Jay is absoultely right to use this solution.

Answer (score 4):

I use this pattern often, especially for specific implementations of generic interfaces. I find it works really well for me.

I like the way it puts the implementations where you can find them. I do it slightly differently - I make them static (it's a style thing, so the interface impls look more like class impls):

```
public interface MathOperator {

    double operate(double a, double b);

    public static MathOperator ADD = new MathOperator() {
        @Override
        public double operate(double a, double b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    };

    public static MathOperator SUBSTRACT = new MathOperator() {
        @Override
        public double operate(double a, double b) {
            return a - b;
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: yes, but for abstract classes I use static, so the code style stays consistent

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem with it. Take `java.lang.String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` for instance. It is almost the same, except that

1. String is not an interface but a final class
2. The `Comparator` is not declared using an anonymous class, but using a static inner class, which is essentially the same

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't like putting implementations within interfaces. I would either:

- make `MathOperator` an `enum`
- keep the interface but have a factory or a static class (say `MathOperators`) with the implementations

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you define each implementation in its own class/file? This would make it clearer and would leave the interface clean.